Running multiple "after" model validators in Pydantic raises only one ValidationError
If a model has more than one failing @model_validator("after"), then only one (the first?) is raised.
Is it possible to tell Pydantic to run all model validators? Are multiple model validators even supported? The docs seem to be silent on this question.
In the below example, I would expect two validation errors, but Pydantic only raises one:
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str
    z: float

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def x_and_y(self):
        if self.x == 1 and self.y == "2":
            raise ValueError("x and y")
        return self

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def y_and_z(self):
        if self.y == "2" and int(self.z) == 3:
            raise ValueError("y and z")
        return self


# This should fail both validators, but only one is raised:
Foo(x=1, y="2", z=3.0)
# pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
#   Value error, x and y [type=value_error, input_value={'x': 1, 'y': '2', 'z': 3.0}, 
# input_type=dict]
#     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/value_error

# If the first validator passes, only then the second one is reported
Foo(x=100, y="2", z=3.0)
# pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
#   Value error, y and z [type=value_error, input_value={'x': 100, 'y': '2', 'z': 3.0}, # input_type=dict]
#     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/value_erro


I think the first validation failure stops the process. Why do you want two exceptions be raised anyway?

@etham so users don't have to find out about errors in their data one at a time.

Seems like there's lots of places where this is being discussed, without an obvious and nice resolution. e.g. this SO question, this GH issue.

I ended up implementing my own BaseModel subclass and decorator which can do this for me. Weird it's not part of Pydantic itself.
